What size wire do I need for a power line 700 feet underground to a residential 100 Amp service?
I need to run a buried power cable from my power at the road to my cabin. It is approximately 700 feet. What size wire do I need to purchase? Will aluminum wire suffice? Thanks!

Is there no way you can get the power company to either a) move the delivery point closer to your cabin or b) give you a 480V service?

First the easy part: Always aluminum for feeders. There can be exceptions - e.g., if it is only a few feet from a meter to a panel or between panels. But for anything long (70 feet or 700 feet), definitely aluminum. It is much less expensive than copper, and is the standard for utility service.
The minimum size for a 100A service feed is 2 AWG aluminum. (For those who are thinking "I asked a question about my 100A subpanel and you told me 2 AWG isn't big enough, there is a special rule for a full service feed that doesn't apply to a subpanel unless it is the same size as the full service feed.)
In order to figure out what you really need, you need to consider voltage drop. That depends on:

Distance - 700 feet
Anticipated maximum load. And no, that is not 100A for a 100A panel.
240V vs. 120V loads
Allowable voltage drop

When you are talking about a building rather than just an individual load or two (e.g., a pump for a well), you need to do a Load Calculation. This takes into account:

Size of the building
Required circuits for kitchen, bathrooms, etc.
HVAC
Cooking equipment (if electric)
Water heating (if electric)

and a bunch of other things. A "cabin" with propane for heating and cooking, no air conditioning and just a few rooms might do fine with 60A or even less. A "cabin" that is an all-electric mini-mansion might need 200A. So the specifics really do matter.
There are also some rules regarding continuous loads, with the result that typically if you have 100A service you would not expect to use more than 80A at a time. And realistically a lot less than that most of the time. But you have to plan your wire size based on the total you might use, even if you only occasionally use that much power at one time.
I'll include one 100A calculation, but I don't think you realistically want to go for that. If you truly need 100A then you actually need a larger panel. Of course, you can, and probably should, install a larger panel, such as a 200A panel, even if your load calculation is very low. That's because:

Large panels cost very little more than small panels.
Spaces are important because you often need extra spaces for a variety of dedicated circuits even though each of those circuits uses very little power.
The working space (30" x 36") required in front of a panel is the same whether you have a 6-space tiny panel or a 42-space big panel or anything in between.

Using the Southwire voltage drop calculator:

100A, 5% = 350 KCMIL (that's huge)
80A, 3% = 500 KCMIL (also huge)
80A, 5% = 250 KCMIL
60A, 3% = 350 KCMIL
60A, 5% = 3/0 (getting better)

Note that all of these are based on 240V. The numbers are much worse for 120V. But most large loads (water heater, cooktop, oven, dryer, EVSE) are either 240V  or a combination 120V/240V with the bulk of the usage at 240V. If the other loads are reasonably well balanced between the two legs of the panel then they are effectively working at 240V with respect to voltage drop. But for comparison:

60A, 5%, 120V = 400 KCMIL

Transformers
Transformers may be a solution. 40A @ 480V (i.e., twice the voltage, half the current - same power as 80A @ 240V) has a 4.33% voltage drop on 3 AWG wire - that's smaller than the wire you actually need to feed to your panel at 240V! The problem is that transformers at that size are not cheap. But a few thousand $ on transformers may save you a lot on wire.
Depending on your utility, it may be possible to either:

Get higher voltage - typically 480V service

You carry that 480V 700 feet to your cabin and install a transformer there. One transformer instead of two.

Get the utility to install their transformer and the meter at the cabin, provide you take care of the 700 feet of feeder. No transformers to buy! But the catch is you will be either installing the feeder on their terms or actually paying them to install the line, which could be quite expensive.

